# How to safely close a C++ mimic of a shell

Tags: c++, shell, exit

I'm trying to code a basic shell in C++ that displays a prompt (`$`) and waits for user input. I can get that down, but the problem is the program ends after the first execution of the user's input.

I have classes for the prompt and commands. The prompt class displays the prompt, gets user input, parses it, and calls the appropriate command->execute() functions. After the first command execution, how do I get the program to return to displaying the command prompt and asking for input? And how do I safely exit the entire program when the user types `exit`?

Below is a snippet of what happens when I run. What I want is that for the `$` to display again (and wait for input), after the `hello`.

```
$ ls -a && echo hello
.   a.log  a.out   command.h  or.h      separate.h  tmp.log
..  and.h  base.h  main.cpp   Prompt.h  tmp.cpp     tst
hello
```

I guess what I'm wondering is, how do I create my own exit function that causes main to return? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about loops?

Comment: And how are you executing the command? `system()`? `exec()`?

Comment: Yes, I know about loops. I'm using execvp to run the commands. I need to start the Prompt from main and I have to create my own exit function that has to be in the Command class.

Comment: @SarahAllec - Are you calling `fork` before `exec*`?

Comment: Yes, I'm forking. The issue is that using execvp with exit doesn't exit the program. So I need another function to call when I want to exit.

Comment: execvp always exits the program. fork creates a new program that you can then exit without exiting the original.

Answer (score -1):

I decided to just use a function that calls std::exit(0). This may/may not be ideal, but since my program is small I'm hoping it should be fine.